# copy paste from userform

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have made a userform. It contains around about 19 combo boxes. Combo boxes have 2 options `YES` and `NO`. then comes a text box infront of each combo box, where comments are typed. What I want is that if user selects no from combo box I want to copy paste the comments of that combo box from userform onto another excel sheet. Right now I am copy pasting all comments. So I want to add this feature as well. Below is the code I am currently using. Can anybody help me in upgrading this code, to add above mentioned feature as well.

```
Private Sub ()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PQCILDMS")

Dim newRow2 As Long

newRow2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1

ws.Cells(newRow2, 1).Value = cmbDMS.Value

Dim newRow3 As Long


newRow3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1

ws.Cells(newRow3, 1).Value = cmbYesNo.Value

Dim newRow4 As Long

newRow4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1

ws.Cells(newRow4, 1).Value = Me.txtComments.Value

ws.Cells(newRow4, 1).Columns.AutoFit


End Sub
```

Comment: _"Combo boxes have 2 options `YES` and `NO`"_ so why not using CheckBoxes?

Comment: Your `combobox` (or a better fit `checkbox`) can be linked to specific cell - so in code you could read value of those `checkbox` linked cell values in order to filter which values to copy and which not

Answer (score 0):

> I want to copy paste the comments of that **combo box** from userform

I think you mean copy TextBox comments?

The best way to handle this is name your ComboBoxes as `ComboBox1, ComboBox2..ComboBox19`. Similarly for the TextBoxes, name them as `TextBox1, textBox2... TextBox19`. Ensure that `TextBox1` is in front of `ComboBox1` and so on.

The reason we do this is so that it become easier to loop. See this example

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For i = 1 To 19
            If Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Value = "No" Then
                .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
                lRow = lRow + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to appropriately renaming texboxes and comboboxes facing each other (suggested approach), you could get the textbox facing a given combobox by checking whether textbox *horizontal axis* (e.g.: its medium ordinate in the Userfom layout) crosses the combobox

so you could put the following code into your userfom code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Cbs As Collection '<--| set this collection as Userform scoped variable
Dim Tbs As Collection '<--| set this collection as Userform scoped variable


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cb As MSForms.ComboBox, tb As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim el As Variant

    With Worksheets("PQCILDMS") '<--| reference sheet
        For Each el In Cbs '<--|loop through all userform comboboxes
            Set cb = el '<--|set the current combobox control
            If cb.value = "NO" Then '<--|if its value is "NO" ...
                Set tb = GetTbNextToCb(cb, Tbs) '<--|... look for the textbox whose horizontal axis is inbetween the current combobox
                If Not tb Is Nothing Then .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).value = tb.value '<--|... if found it then write its content in referenced sheet column "A" next available cell
            End If
        Next el
    End With
End Sub


Function GetTbNextToCb(cb As MSForms.ComboBox, Tbs As Collection) As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim tb As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim cbYMin As Long, cbYMax As Long, tbYMin As Long, tbYMax As Long
    Dim el As Variant

    GetYMinMax cb, cbYMin, cbYMax '<--| get minimum and maximum ordinate of passed combobox

    For Each el In Tbs '<--|loop through all userform textboxes
        Set tb = el '<--|set the current textbox control
        If IsAxisInBetween(tb, cbYMin, cbYMax) Then '<--|if current textbox horizontal axis inbetween passed combobox minimum and maximum ordinates...
            Set GetTbNextToCb = tb '...return the found textbox...
            Exit Function '<--|... and exit function (no need to iterate over remaining textboxes)
        End If
    Next el
End Function

Function IsAxisInBetween(ctrl As Control, yMinRef As Long, yMaxRef As Long) As Boolean
    Dim yMin As Long, yMax As Long

    GetYMinMax ctrl, yMin, yMax '<--| get minimum and maximum ordinates of the control in the userform
    IsAxisInBetween = (yMax + yMin) / 2 <= yMaxRef And (yMax + yMin) / 2 >= yMinRef '<--| check if the control orizontal axis is in between the reference ordinates
End Function

Sub GetYMinMax(ctrl As Control, yMin As Long, yMax As Long)
    With ctrl
        yMin = .Top '<--| get the minimum ordinate of the control in the Userform
        yMax = .Top + .Height '<--| get the maximum ordinate of the control in the Userform
    End With
End Sub



'this sub will run at Userfom loading
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set Cbs = GetCtrls("ComboBox") '<--| gather all Userform comboboxes in this collection
    Set Tbs = GetCtrls("TextBox") '<--| gather all Userform texboxes in this collection
End Sub

Function GetCtrls(ctrlTypeName As String) As Collection
    Dim coll As New Collection '<--| declare and set a new Collection object
    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls '<--| loop through all Userform controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = ctrlTypeName Then '<--| if it matches the passed Type name...
            coll.Add ctrl, ctrl.Name '<--| ... then add it to the collection
        End If
    Next ctrl
    Set GetCtrls = coll '<--| return the collection
End Function
```

Comment: @ShajeeRehman: it'd be nice of you to give feedbakcs to people trying and help you